# Bulk genealogy data

Tags: usa

I'm wondering if there is a source for bulk US genealogy data (e.g. a database containing ids for individuals and relationships between parents, siblings, children and spouses).

I know there exist commercial sites like ancestry.com, but they do not expose their data to researchers or developers for analysis.

Comment: Hi welcome to Genealogy and Family History, I would suggest taking the [tour] and reviewing [help] on what is in scope of this forum. As written it is likely out of this site.  It may be more appropriate for the [opendata.se]  site on SE.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'll close the question and repost on open data.

Comment: No, I can tell you with 99.9999% certainty that no such comprehensive database exists, nor, would I argue, should it. In any case I am very unclear on what kind of data you are after, or what you intend to do with it.

Comment: @HarryVervet Ancestry has partnered with Google and if you do DNA and do not opt out your tree is part of that. It is just not public. As far as I am aware you cannot get access to it. There is also GEDMatch which maybe one could write an API. There are some larger public family trees that can be easily found that number the 10s of thousands of nodes.. with what quality some of those are.. is another question